# How to solve Ajax form validation for multiple file upload?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm stuck on this for 2 weeks now.. All my google search links are purple and I haven't find a solution yet :s

I have a form that uploads multiple files together with 2 email addresses. All the error validations work but when I upload files I can't send my form anymore.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#uform" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var files = document.getElementsByName("files[]");
        fEmail=$("#fEmail").val();
        yEmail=$("#yEmail").val();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            data: "files[]="+files+"&yEmail="+yEmail+"&fEmail="+fEmail,
            success: function(html){ 

                for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {       
                    if(files[x].value == '' || files[x].value == '0'){
                        $("#uploaderror").html("No file selected!");
                    }
                 }

                if (html.trim()=='fEmailError') {
                    $("#uploaderror").html("Please enter a valid Email address!");
                }

                if (html.trim()=='yEmailError')  {
                    $("#uploaderror").html("Please enter a valid Email address!");
                }

                if (html.trim()=='uploadIsSuccess')    {
                    $("#uploadsuccess").html("Success!");
                }

            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Search for application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the success/error/complete callback options & take it from there:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```